# Mongoid criteria that returns nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I need to create a mongoid criteria which will return nothing. I couldn't find any "none"-kind of method, so I'm doing Model.where(id: nil) or Model.any_in(id: nil) instead.
However this is not nice, and will also query the db.

I would like to add my own selector to mongoid that will return an empty result without even querying the db (such as Model.none()), but don't know where/how to do it. Can somebody help?

Note: I need this because the caller might chain the criteria without having to know it's already empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What version of Mongoid are you on? Because when I try `Model.none` it returns an empty set:

```
Model.none
Model.none.count # => 0
```

`none` was added in version 4. If you can’t update to that version, you could try integrating the change. These methods at [at line 309 in `/lib/mongoid.criteria.rb`](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb#L309) need to be defined:

```
def none
  @none = true and self
end

def empty_and_chainable?
  !!@none
end
```

`Mongoid::Contextual#create_context` also needs [to be changed](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb#L51):

```
def create_context
  return None.new(self) if empty_and_chainable?
  embedded ? Memory.new(self) : Mongo.new(self)
end
```

Then you can include [`/lib/mongoid/contextual/none.rb'](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/contextual/none.rb).

**EDIT**: [this Gist backports `.none` to Mongoid 3](https://gist.github.com/backspace/d77d93c892da8c2577f9):

```
module Mongoid
  class Criteria
    def none
      @none = true and self
    end

    def empty_and_chainable?
      !!@none
    end
  end

  module Contextual  
    class None
      include ::Enumerable

      # Previously included Queryable, which has been extracted in v4
      attr_reader :collection, :criteria, :klass

      def blank?
        !exists?
      end
      alias :empty? :blank?

      attr_reader :criteria, :klass

      def ==(other)
        other.is_a?(None)
      end

      def each
        if block_given?
          [].each { |doc| yield(doc) }
          self
        else
          to_enum
        end
      end

      def exists?; false; end

      def initialize(criteria)
        @criteria, @klass = criteria, criteria.klass
      end

      def last; nil; end

      def length
        entries.length
      end
      alias :size :length
    end

    private

    def create_context
      return None.new(self) if empty_and_chainable?
      embedded ? Memory.new(self) : Mongo.new(self)
    end  
  end

  module Finders
    delegate :none, to: :with_default_scope
  end
end
```

Comment: Right, exists in version 4, but not in 3.1.4 which I use. I'll try to copy the class None to my project then. Or is that not a good idea?

Comment: I updated my answer with what I think should work to integrate `None`. It’s perhaps frowned upon but the changes didn’t seem that far-reaching, so it seems okay.

Comment: So I'm trying to monkey patch it like this https://gist.github.com/stanley90/5a5f35be733642e2afc9 (in config/initializers) but doesn't work. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You have [an error on line 13](https://gist.github.com/stanley90/5a5f35be733642e2afc9#file-mongoid-none-rb-L13). I [forked your gist](https://gist.github.com/backspace/d77d93c892da8c2577f9).

Comment: ahhh that wasn’t an error. Hmm, my gist doesn’t work either. Let me see…

Comment: Success! The problem was that various things have been renamed or broken up, which is often the trouble with trying to backport. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/backspace/d77d93c892da8c2577f9) worked for me on Mongoid 3. I’ll update the answer.